# Optimizar consulta mysql Sorting result

Tags: mysql, sql, optimización

Como dice el titulo, la consulta que tengo es esta:

```
SELECT id, first_date_order, last_date_order, 
                (SELECT o.created_at 
                 FROM orders o 
                 WHERE o.customer_id = c.id
                 ORDER BY o.created_at DESC
                 LIMIT 1) 
                 as last_date_order_real,
                 (SELECT o.created_at 
                 FROM orders o 
                 WHERE o.customer_id = c.id
                 ORDER BY o.created_at ASC
                 LIMIT 1) 
                 as first_date_order_real
FROM customer c
WHERE orders > 0
```

Basicamente lo que hace es, coger todos los customers que tienen algun pedido, la fecha de su primer pedido y la fecha de su ultimo pedido, y luego calcular a partir de la relacion order <-> customer, la fecha real tanto del primer pedido como del ultimo.

Tarda algo mas de 4 minutos en ejecutarse, la mayor parte del tiempo la pasa en el estado Sorting result, imagino que el problema de la consulta es que para cada customer (1M approx), tiene que hacer 2 consultas, y para cada una de esas consultas tiene que ordenar los registros de manera ascendente y descendente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tienes para qué hacer una subconsulta para cada uno de esos datos que quieres. Basta con hacer un `LEFT JOIN`, y usar `MAX` y `MIN`:

```
SELECT  c.id, 
        c.first_date_order, 
        c.last_date_order, 
        MAX(o.created_at) last_date_order_real,
        MIN(o.created_at) first_date_order_real
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON c.id = o.customer_id
WHERE c.orders > 0
GROUP BY c.id, 
         c.first_date_order, 
         c.last_date_order;
```

Comment: Creo que esta solución es perfecta, lo unico que el GROUP BY teniendo en cuenta que las fechas son DATETIME, es practicamente imposible que el mismo customer tenga para la misma fecha varios pedidos, mejor quitarlos y agrupar solo por c.id no?

Comment: @VictorCompany no, porque las fechas que estoy usando en el GROUP BY son las fechas provenientes de la tabla `customer`, debe haber sólo un valor por cada customer

Comment: En principio estoy usándola agrupando solo por el c.id y funciona perfect y rapidísimo, al agrupar por el id del customer se queda solo 1 registro por customer que es la idea. Gracias!!

Comment: Interesantemente, MySQL funcionaría correctamente si solo le haces un `GROUP BY` por `c.id` (asumiendo que se trata de la PK), aun en las versiones mas recientes donde han "restringido" el uso del `GROUP BY` para evitar consultas/resultados erróneos ([MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)). Pero eso sí, con otros motores de base de datos, la consulta te lanzaría un error.  Y en lo personal, me parece mejor práctica de mantenerlo de la forma que lo tiene Lamak en la respuesta.

Comment: @VictorCompany estás usando una característica única de mysql, pero el resultado sería el mismo si agrupas por las otras columnas, y sería estándar SQL, te recomiendo que lo hagas. (*disclaimer: hay versiones de postgresql que permiten el agrupar sólo por una columna, en cuanto el resto dependan funcionalmente de ella, que es este caso particular. Pero en general, recomiendo agrupar por todas)

Comment: Gracias! Lección aprendida.